# fs.readdir and fs.readfile and regex

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

This is a Node application, running express server. I have a folder with text files in it. I need to be able to go into each one of those files inside the folder, and extract lines that include a word "SAVE".

I am stuck at this step.

```
app.get('/logJson', function (req, res) {
  const logsFolder = 'C:/logs/';
  fs.readdir(logsFolder, (err, files) => {
    if (err) {
      res.send("[empty]");
      return;
    }
    files.forEach(function(filename){
      var logFiles = fs.readFileSync (logsFolder + filename, 'ascii').toString().split("\n");
      console.log(logFiles + "\n");
    })
  })
})
```

I cannot figure out where do I include this:

```
var log = (logFiles.split(/.*SAVE.*/g)||['no result found'])[0];
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to print out all lines containing the word `SAVE`, you could do it like this.

*Remark: I did not run this code.*

```
app.get('/logJson', function (req, res) {
  const logsFolder = 'C:/logs/';
  fs.readdir(logsFolder, (err, files) => {
    if (err) {
      res.send("[empty]");
      return;
    }
    var lines = [];
    files.forEach(function(filename) {
      var logFileLines = fs.readFileSync (logsFolder + filename, 'ascii').toString().split("\n");

      // go through the list of logFileLines
      logFileLines.forEach(function(logFileLine) {

        // if the current line matches SAVE, it will be stored in the variable lines
        if(logFileLine.match(/SAVE/)) {
          lines.push(logFileLine);
        }
      })
    })

    // the variable lines is printed to the console
    console.log(lines);
  })
})
```

Comment: If I need to do more parsing on the current output, where should I place my parse code?

Comment: @Tony It depends, what do you need to do?

Comment: I figured it out. Now I have another problem if my folder has other folders inside, it breaks my code and here is the error `fs.js:603
  var r = binding.read(fd, buffer, offset, length, position);
Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.readSync (fs.js:603:19)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:438:24)
    at C:\Users\admin\Desktop\folder\server.js:1
6:30
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at C:\Users\admin\Desktop\folder\server.js:1
5:12
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)

C:\Users\admin\Desktop\folder>